# How do I navigate to an Angular route via URL with query params?

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack, angular5

In my current project I have a user profile route which I currently have set to navigate to dynamically.  That is to say that when the user navigates to that page the user's _id is passed to localStorage and then MongoDB is queried with that _id.  This then loads all of the relevant user data to display and everything works well.

This presents the problem that users can't navigate to their profile directly by pasting a link in the address bar or clicking on a link passed via email or sms.  There isn't even a URL to copy unless parameters are passed via ActivatedRoute.  But the URL is now basically "just for show" because I am not doing anything with the parameters in the URL.

I would like to create functionality that allows for direct navigation via URL.  Below is my current attempt which is not working because, I believe, the page is rendered before the API responds.  How do I go about fixing this?

Thank You.

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-profile',
  templateUrl: './view-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-profile.component.css']
})
export class ViewProfileComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{

  member: any;
  isAdmin: boolean;      
  areas: any[];
  params: any;
  canDisplay: boolean = false;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {        
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isAdmin = this.authService.isAdmin();
    localStorage.setItem('member_id', this.member_id);
    this.getMember(this.route.snapshot.params['user_id']);        
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.member);
  }

  getMember(url) {
    this.authService.getProfile(url).subscribe(member => {
      this.member = member;
    });        
  }

  getParams() {
    this.route.params.map(params => {
      console.log(params);
    });
  }

  setMemberData() {        
    let tempArray = [];
    tempArray = this.member.practice.split(',');
    this.areas = tempArray;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to use this.member_id before you are requesting it from your service, let alone before the service returns a value.

In `ngOnInit` subscribe to `ActiveRoute` and when that returns then call your `authService`. (You can think of  `map()` as a middle-ware which transforms the response, subscribe is used to invoke the observable)

This will ensure that the member_id is available when you are passing it to your service and setting local storage.

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.authService.getProfile(params.member_id).subscribe(member => {
    this.member = member;
    localStorage.setItem('member_id', this.member.member_id);
    });  
});
```